# Excel solver for a table

Tags: excel, average, solver

Trying to use the solver add-in for Excel to get the min average for a range of cells in the following table:

[image: Data table]

Where PT = processing time, DD = Due date
The cell Tardiness has the following formula; `=IF([@[Cum. PT]]-[@DD]>0;[@[Cum. PT]]-[@DD];0)` --> Basically Time past the due date, but if below due date = 0
Cumulative cells have the obvious formulas.

The cell in the bottom right is the average, this is the value I want to optimize, this should be done by switching the order of rows.

Is it possible to do this in solver? That it just switches order of entire rows?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, but the approach I would try is to use VLOOKUP or INDIRECT to fetch the Real PT. Solver would need to be setup as a mixed integer problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your problem is stated, it can be solved with the following steps ...

1. Put `Row`, `Real PT`, and `DD` in a separate source table (`SourceTable`).

Like this.

```
Row Real PT DD
1   8   30
2   10  14
3   13  68
4   18  53
5   16  58
6   12  18
7   11  78
8   14  26
```

2. Build your table where `Real PT` is calculated as `=VLOOKUP(A2,SourceTable,2)`, and `DD` is calculated as `=VLOOKUP(A2,SourceTable,3)`. All other calculations should be as you have already defined.
3. Set up Solver with the following:

   - Objective Cell is `$F$10`
   - Minimize
   - By Changing `$A$2:$A$9`
   - Constraints `$A$2:$A$9 <= 8`, `$A$2:$A$9 >= 1`, `$A$2:$A$9 = AllDifferent`, `$A$2:$A$9 = integer`
   - Solving method = Evolutionary

With these, I get the following result ...

[image]

... which may or may not be acceptable - it seems the 84 day tardiness may be excessive. Constraints could be added for maximum tardiness.

**Edit** - You can also specify GRG Nonlinear as the solution method, but you will need to go into options and pick multistart. GRG Nonlinear takes much longer to come to a solution than Evolutionary.

Answer (score 0):

Solver can not change positions of rows.

<strike>For your case I would just sort Tardiness from smallest to largest which would give you the smallest average cumulative tardiness.</strike>

Comment: In this formula tardiness is dependent on the cumulative PT. Therefore, this would not give an optimal solution